# Save a big function in different script outside of a class in python

Tags: python, function, class

I have a very big function (containing lots of elif) in a class. 
This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Gui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)  
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()
def testsubmit(self):
    orientation = self.panelorientation.get()
    numberofcols = float(self.columns.get())
    numberofrows = float(self.rows.get())
    if orientation == "Portrait":
        if numberofrows == 1 and numberofcols ==1:
            self.entries['Number of Helio Std. Rail (L=84)'].delete(0,END)
            self.entries['Number of Helio Std. Rail (L=84)'].insert(0, 1 )
        elif numberofrows == 1 and numberofcols ==2:
            self.entries['Number of Helio Std. Rail (L=84)'].delete(0,END)
            self.entries['Number of Helio Std. Rail (L=84)'].insert(0, 2 )
            self.entries['Helio Std. Splice Kit'].delete(0,END)
            self.entries['Helio Std. Splice Kit'].insert(0, 0)                
        elif numberofrows == 1 and numberofcols ==3:
            self.entries['Number of Helio Std. Rail (L=124)'].delete(0,END)
            self.entries['Number of Helio Std. Rail (L=124)'].insert(0, 2)
            self.entries['Helio Std. Splice Kit'].delete(0,END)
            self.entries['Helio Std. Splice Kit'].insert(0, 0)  
            ...
            ...

 def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Gui(root)
    app.testsubmit()
    root.mainloop()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I know this is not the efficient way to write bunch of `if` and `elif` in a single script. Can I write this function in another script and use inside in the class?

Comment: since every if asks `numberofrows == 1`, you could nest it

Answer (score 2):

You could define `testsubmit` in **extra_gui.py:**

```
def testsubmit(self):
    ...
```

then define it as a method of the `Gui` class like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import extra_gui as EG

class Gui(Frame):
    testsubmit = EG.testsubmit
```

Comment: I am trying to use the function in another function of the same class:         self.quit_B = Button(self, text="BoM", command=self.testsubmit);  The error message is:   File "C:\Users\test_1.py", line 15, in initUI
    self.quit_B = Button(self, text="BoM", command=self.testsubmit)
AttributeError: 'Gui' object has no attribute 'testsubmit'

Comment: I used exactly the way you answered. Still showing me the error: AttributeError: 'Gui' object has no attribute 'EG'

Comment: If you get the error `'Gui' object has no attribute 'testsubmit'` then make sure `testsubmit = EG.testsubmit` is defined *before* the function raising that error gets called. Try putting `testsubmit = EG.testsubmit` immediately after `class Gui(Frame):`. If you get `'Gui' object has no attribute 'EG'` then you must be writing `self.EG` somewhere. You're getting that error because `EG` is a module-level global variable, not an attribute of instances of `Gui`. If that doesn't help, post the code you are running so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

in gui.py

```
class Gui:
    foo = 'foos'
    bar = 'bars'

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.foo = f


def fcn(s, b):
    s.bar = b

# associate fcn with Gui
Gui.fcn = fcn
```

Then, in the shell

```
>>> import gui
>>> bb = b.Gui('aaa')
>>>
>>> bb.foo
'aaa'
>>> bb.bar
'bars'
>>>
>>>
>>> bb.fcn('bbbbbb')
>>> bb.foo
'aaa'
>>> bb.bar
'bbbbbb'
```